# Obtención de probabilidad condicionada en variables binarias

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente conjunto:

```
    1 2 3 4
r01 1 0 1 1
r02 1 1 0 1
r03 0 0 1 0
r04 0 0 1 0
```

Código para crear la tabla:

```
initial <- data.frame(c(1,1,0,0), c(0,1,0,0), c(1,0,1,1),c(1,1,0,0), row.names = c("r01","r02","r03","r04"))
colnames(initial) <- c(1:4)
```

Necesito obtener la probabilidad condicional, por ejemplo si escojo `r03` la probabilidad condicional de haber escogido `r03` y evaluarlo con `r01` sería:

```
          |r03=0 |r03=1
    r01=0 | 1/3  | 0/1
    r01=1 | 2/3  | 1/1
```

Otro ejemplo, si escojo `r03` y evalúo con `r02`:

```
          |r03=0 |r03=1
    r02=0 | 0/3  | 1/1
    r02=1 | 3/3  | 0/1
```

No sé como implementar esta tabla o directamente obtener el valor de cada celda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La [solución](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47272251/6836377) que ya has recibido en el sitio en inglés es realmente buena y sumamente simple, simplemente voy a traducirla y ampliarla un poco:

```
tin <- data.frame(matrix(t(initial), ncol = 4, byrow = FALSE))
colnames(tin) <- rownames(initial)
tab <- table(tin$r01, tin$r03)
prop.table(tab,2)
```

En primer lugar, la parte fácil, "trasponemos" el `data.frame` original y lo convertimos en una matriz, mediante [`t()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/t.html) y [`matrix()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/matrix.html). Llevamos los nombres de las filas a las columnas de la matriz mediante [`colnames()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colnames.html). Obtendremos algo así:

```
  r01 r02 r03 r04
1   1   1   0   0
2   0   1   0   0
3   1   0   1   1
4   1   1   0   0
```

Luego mediante [`table()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/table.html) aplicado a las dos columnas que elijamos construimos un `table` que computa las combinaciones de cada factor. Por ejemplo si lo aplicamos a las columnas `r01`y `r03` que sería `tin[, c(1,3)]`, es decir:

```
  r01 r03
1   1   0
2   0   0
3   1   1
4   1   0
```

Aplicando: `tab <- table(tin$r01, tin$r03)` obtendríamos:

```
    0 1
  0 1 0
  1 2 1
```

Que se lee:

- una sola combinación `(0,0)`
- ninguna `(0,1)`
- 2 combinaciones `(1,0)`
- 1 combinación `(1,1)`

Y por último calcular las proporciones de cada combinación mediante `prop.table()`. Que funciona de la siguiente forma: al indicar `margin=2` le decimos que calcule de forma "vertical", veamos:

```
    0 1
  0 1 0
  1 2 1
    3 1 <- suma vertical
```

Es decir:

```
    0    1
  0 1/3 0/1
  1 2/3 1/1
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación, no me acordé de postear la respuesta en el foro español.